# If I close all ports via our firewall except for the single port used by our forex broker can I still be hacked by the broker or someone else?

Tags: network, firewalls

We have closed all ports on our firewall except for port 5011 which is the only port that is required to be open on our server so that our server can receive price data and send buy and sell orders to our forex broker. We have restricted access to only 2 remote servers which belong to our forex broker, all other outbound and inbound traffic has been blocked.

Is it possible for our forex broker to gain remote access to our server and steal files on our server via hacking through our Cisco firewall, given that we are always connected to our broker's servers?

Given that all ports are closed on our server except for port 5011 (which is always open but always being used to receive real-time streaming price data) is it possible for a third-party hacker who somehow finds out our IP address to do a port scan and find out if the trading platform software we are using via port 5011 has a vulnerability in it and if so gain full remote access to our server?

Answer (score 1):

There's not enough information here (or indeed, possibly anywhere) to answer your question, but I can help point the way to finding the answer.

> is it possible for {anybody} to gain remote access to our server and steal files on our server via hacking

This is a question that depends almost entirely on the security of the server software, and to some extent on the permissions it runs with. What server is it? Who wrote it? How much security review has it received? How often does it get updates? How many of those updates are security patches? How quickly do you apply them? What language is it written in? What third-party libraries does it depend on? What OS permissions does the process have? Is it sandboxed at all?

A firewall can be useful for restricting access to vulnerable software, but the buck ultimately stops with the security of the software itself (and, if it does get compromised, then the OS security determines what the attacker can access). If you can help it, don't run software that you aren't confident of the security of. If your software is sufficiently ironclad, a firewall is wholly unnecessary (although in practice it's a good idea to use one to reduce attack surface anyhow; perfect security does not, in practice, exist).

> given that all ports are closed on our server except for port 5011 is it possible for a hacker who somehow finds out our IP address to do a port scan

Yep. That's standard network recon stuff, both the IP search and the port scan. Now, depending on the protocol used and the OS / firewall behavior, it might be difficult to determine the status of the port, but in general you should expect it to be possible to find open ports.

Mind you, rejecting all external traffic (either at the server software, or at the firewall) does mean that the port scan would need to come from (or look like it comes from) the forex broker. But you can't completely trust that e.g. their network doesn't host any backdoored or otherwise malicious machines / users.

> find out if the trading platform software we are using via port 5011 has a vulnerability in it

Once again, we're back to the sort of questions in my second paragraph. Is your trading software externally known? Does it have any CVEs? Does it identify itself in any way (e.g. via a version string transmitted when you connect, or by consistently using a particular port, or so on)? Is your company known to use it? Is its source code public? Is it available publicly at all?

> if so gain full remote access to our server and then steal our sensitive files

Same deal, but about the OS security again. What user account does the server software run as? What permissions does that account have? Does the software drop any permissions it doesn't need? Have you applied the principle of least privilege to the server software? Is there any way (e.g. through a broker process) you could gate access to the sensitive data? Does the server actually need to be on the same logical - or even physical - machine as your sensitive files? What security boundaries are in place protecting those files? Are they encrypted, and if so, where's the key? Do you have access to the files audited?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Via our firewall we have closed *all* ports that are being used by *all* Windows services, does this mean we don't need to apply any OS security patches anymore as any vulnerabilities in the OS software can't be exploited by a hacker as all the ports are closed?  Also, the forex broker knows what version of the trading software we are using so it would also know the vulnerabilities in its own trading software, does this mean it would be possible or easy for the broker to gain access to our computer and steal our sensitive files?